# 2 different storyboards for portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

is it possible to create 2 storyboards and access each of them depending on the device orientation? I tried this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
              UIStoryboard *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Storyboardland.storyboard"];


    }else if (UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        UIStoryboard *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard"];

    }}
```

...but does not work?? Any errors I am making??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this answer to a previous post (iPhone Storyboard: different scene for portrait and landscape)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777629/iphone-storyboard-different-scene-for-portrait-and-landscape/8863381#8863381)   might solve your problem. It explains how to have a different views for portrait and landscape modes, but still uses the same view controller.