# UIView switching animation for landscape and portrait scene in storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation, uistoryboard

I'm trying to design different layouts for my view controller. After googling, I've got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777629/iphone-storyboard-different-scene-for-portrait-and-landscape/8863381#8863381) answer from SO. Basically, the answer instructs me to setup 2 scenes, one for landscape and one for portrait, when the device rotates, hide one and show the other one.

And my question is what if I want to add a *sweet* animation for the rotation process? For example, since I can setup the *same* view on different scenes, can I set the motion path for these views and disappear? Or, if it is easier, can I add some rotation and fade out animation?

I'm quite green with Core Animation, so a detailed explanation is very useful for me. Big big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here. The main methods you are looking for to do any of this are:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

and

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

If you want to move the elements around the screen while the rotation is happening you will be best off changing the frames of the elements rather than creating a separate view file. Using any motion animation would require some mapping between the two and I have never heard of anything like this before. Again, if you just change the frames though, you can preform basically any screen movements you would like (for views and subviews).

To do the fading you could just throw an animation block in the first method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration 
                     animations:^{
    // set alphas for old and new views here.
}];
```

Comment: I want to use two view files because I'm not quite familiar with layout in code, like setting up constraints and stuff, and I believe it is a good idea to separate view layout from other code stuff. But if I really wanted to perform view movement transition animation, is it a must to give up on storyboard?

Comment: Or is it possible to read only the layout information (frames and bounds for each view), so I can replace the views using animation stuff?