# ios Best Practices for rotation

Tags: ios, constraints, landscape-portrait

My App with a portrait screen is done

It uses storyboards.

It needs to support landscape.

Lanscape layout is completely different (Controls moving to different parts of the screen) than Portrait but uses the same set of controls

What are the best practices -

Start with Portrait and copy the storyboard to Landscape
This forces me to maintain two storyboards all the time.

-OR-

Keep using constraints and programmatically change the constraints to move the controls at run time.

-OR- 
Something else

Answer (score 0):

I would add two container views to each View Controller that you want to show different stuff for every orientation so when the orientation changes you hide and show the different containers whenever you want (landscape and portrait).... because two Storyboards is a lot of work and a lot more complicated.

Maybe you want to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777629/iphone-storyboard-different-scene-for-portrait-and-landscape/8863381#8863381)

Hope it helps!